# Including records that are missing in another dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do something along the lines of a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or `WHERE NOT IN`, but am struggling with the syntax.

This is the results set I've got so far, let's called it **PlanActStaff**:

```sql
SELECT 
    CTE_PlanStaff.RegisterID,
    CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityDate,
    CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityTime,
    CTE_PlanStaff.TT_StaffID,
    CTE_ActStaff.ActStaffID
FROM
    CTE_PlanStaff
INNER JOIN
    CTE_ActStaff
ON
    CTE_PlanStaff.RegisterID = CTE_ActStaff.RegisterID
AND
    CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityDate = CTE_ActStaff.ActSessionDate
AND
    CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityTime = CTE_ActStaff.ActSessionStartTime
```

For each record in this result set I want the query to go back and check my `CTE_PlanStaff` CTE to see whether the `ActStaffID` exists for the current combination of `RegisterID`, `TT_ActivityDate` and `TT_ActivityTime` in `CTE_PlanStaff`.

So for example, if a record being checked in **PlanActStaff** looked like this:

```
| RegisterID | TT_ActivityDate | TT_ActivityTime | TT_StaffID | ActStaffID |
|------------|-----------------|-----------------|------------|------------|
|   98688    |    2016-01-04   |      11:20      |    2453    |    2067    |
```

`CTE_PlanStaff` would then be filtered on the same combination of `RegisterID`, `TT_ActivityDate` and `TT_ActivityTime`, so `CTE_PlanStaff` might then have these records to compare:

```
| RegisterID | TT_ActivityDate | TT_ActivityTime | TT_StaffID |
|------------|-----------------|-----------------|------------|
|   98688    |    2016-01-04   |      11:20      |    2500    |
|   98688    |    2016-01-04   |      11:20      |    2453    |
```

I'd then like the `ActStaffID` value of `2067` checked against each `TT_StaffID` in the filtered `CTE_PlanStaff` and if the `ActStaffID` isn't listed to leave that record showing in my **PlanActStaff** query.

I've tried to adapt **PlanActStaff** as follows...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            CTE_PlanStaff.RegisterID,
            CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityDate,
            CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityTime,
            CTE_PlanStaff.TT_StaffID,
            CTE_ActStaff.ActStaffID
        FROM
            CTE_PlanStaff
        INNER JOIN
            CTE_ActStaff
        ON
            CTE_PlanStaff.RegisterID = CTE_ActStaff.RegisterID
        AND
            CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityDate = CTE_ActStaff.ActSessionDate
        AND
            CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityTime = CTE_ActStaff.ActSessionStartTime
    ) PlanActStaff
WHERE
    ActStaffID NOT IN (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            CTE_PlanStaff
        WHERE
            CTE_PlanStaff.RegisterID = PlanActStaff.RegisterID
        AND
            CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityDate = PlanActStaff.TT_ActivityDate
        AND
            CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityTime = PlanActStaff.TT_ActivityTime
    )
```

...but I get the following error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I started looking at `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, but I can't figure out how to both filter `CTE_PlanStaff` against the current record and then check the staffID fields.

Comment: It looks like you're ultimate comparing CTE_PlanStaff with CTE_PlanStaff (since that's what's used to generate the results of your PlanActStaff subquery). Rather than show the results from your queries perhaps it would be easier to understand if you just included sample data from your tables and expected results.

Comment: From what I get the error occurs because of the `WHERE ActStaffID NOT IN (SELECT * ...` You cannot use `IN` and then use `SELECT *` if this results in multiple columns to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WHERE
>
> ```
> ActStaffID NOT IN (
>     SELECT *
>     FROM
>         CTE_PlanStaff
>     WHERE
>         CTE_PlanStaff.RegisterID = PlanActStaff.RegisterID
>     AND
>         CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityDate = PlanActStaff.TT_ActivityDate
>     AND
>         CTE_PlanStaff.TT_ActivityTime = PlanActStaff.TT_ActivityTime
> )
> ```

you should select only one field to be compared against 'ActStaffID'

Comment: Ahh yes, now that I think about it, that makes perfect sense. Thanks, I'll test it out.